# NotFoundHttpException error in laravel

Tags: laravel

This is my view:

```
<img src="../public/{{ $axid->img }}">
```

and this is my route :

```
Route::get('/ax/{axid}', function($id) {
$axid = show::find($id);
return view('ax', compact('axid'));
```

Images are uploaded in public/uploads and show is model name. However, I have this error:

> NotFoundHttpException

...what is the problem?

Comment: This can just be: `<img src="{{ $axid->img }}">` you dont need to add `/public`

Comment: What is `show::` a model? Are you calling it correctly?

Comment: Why on earth are you not doing this in a controller more to the point?

Comment: ALSO... Where is the view with the `a href=""` we need to see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your image resolving code is functioning properly and that you are returning the full url of the image you want to show, then change your view code to:

```
<img src="{{ asset($axid->img) }}">
```

Comment: There is no controller...Read his `Route::`

Answer (score 1):

Please see how you **should** be setting this out:

View before moving to this a href..: `<a href="/ax/{{ $variable->id }}">Get ID</a>`

Route: `Route::get('/ax/{id}', 'AxidController@get');`

Controller with me assuming `Show` is your model name:

```
public function get($id, Show $show)
    {
        $axid = $show->find($id);

        return view('page', compact('axid'));
    }
```

On the page of `ax/{id}`:

```
<img src="{{ $axid->image }}">
```